# Twitter re-tweet with comment using api version 1.1

Tags: php, api, twitter

I have tried to re-tweet without comment than it is working using php sdk like

```
$connection = new Twitter_TwitterOAuth($this->registry->config->twitter_key, $this->registry->config->twitter_secret, $postData['token'], $postData['secret']);
$connection->post('statuses/retweet/'.$postData['id']);
```

but for re-tweet with comment i did not found any help and also in twitter API I checked that there is no parameter of comment when re-tweet.

I am referring this API method.

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/:id.json

in this only two param id and trim user and no comment parameter is given with this API call.

Can any one help me on this for re-tweet with comment using API of twitter?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like "retweets with comments" are just like normal tweets, with a permalink to another tweet at the end. So POST statuses/update with a link to a tweet should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer wil check and give feedback.

Comment: @IIan can you please provide a example because i am not able "retweets with comments"  using api.